# Correctly implemented but font does not appear, fallback font appears

Tags: css, font-face

So I've looked through stackoverflow to implement a custom font and this is what I resulted in after looking at other peoples code:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "pixel";
    src: url("../pixel.ttf");
}

h1#largetitle{
    font-family: "pixel", sans-serif;
}
```

However, the pixel font does not show, instead the sans-serif font shows and I'm unsure as to why the pixel font isnt showing up.

Comment: What directory is your font located in? How about your CSS?

Comment: @brouxhaha: the css is in a css folder which is in the rootand the font is in the root

Comment: That's why then. The file path is in relation to the css file: Try this: `src: url(../pixel.ttf);`

Comment: @brouxhaha: it didnt do anything unfortunately

Comment: @brouxhaha: or it did...? I just got so confused, I'm woprking on this html in eclipse and in the web browser it didnt show up but when i pushed it to github, it suddenly shows up on the internet. It still shows up as sans-serif on eclipse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it didn't work in eclipse was because the type of browser that eclipse uses and the browser I was using, (Google Chrome), to view the font were two different browsers.

The font didn't show properly on eclipse but the code was working properly so it did show up on Google Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a directory like the following it should work.

```
project/
|
|--css/             
|   |-- main.css
    ...

|--fonts/
|   |--pixel.ttf
    ...    
|-- ...
```

Make sure you haven't left any uppercase letter in the font name or the source file.